# How to enter many points in the run process?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am now figuring out a problem: enter several coordinates of  points, then put them into three list, one for the points which are above the line y=x, one exactly on it, and one below it.

I am a novice, so i am really confusing. 
Please also tell me how can i enter these points in the run time, not in the coding time.

Comment: do you know `input()` ?

Comment: https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/python/getting-started/input-and-output/tutorial/

Comment: @pythonnoob Upvoted on you. By the way, you could use input.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a list of points of the form (x, y), where x and y are int or float values. Suppose this list is called `points`. Then, the following will work:

```
below = []
on = []
above = []
for coordinate_pair in points:
    if coordinate_pair[0] < coordinate_pair[1]: # That is, x < y, so (x, y) is above the line y = x
        above.append(coordinate_pair)
    elif coordinate_pair[0] == coordinate_pair[1]:
        on.append(coordinate_pair)
    # I'll leave the rest to you, since I believe this is a homework assignment
```

If you want to enter these points during runtime, you can use `float(input("Enter a value for x: "))` to get x-values and `float(input("Enter a value for y: "))` to get y-values.

Comment: `points` would just be the list you start out with; `points` would be a list of tuples of the form (x, y).

Comment: what does 0 and 1 mean in the if loop?

Comment: Those are the indices of your tuples. A tuple may be of the form (4, 2), where the x-coordinate is 4 and the y-coordinate is 2. (4, 2)[0] == 4 and (4, 2)[1] == 2. This is basic tuple indexing.